# conda update anaconda=VersionNumber Not working

Tags: anaconda

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Here says that we can use `conda update anaconda=VersionNumber` to update anaconda, but I ran `conda update anaconda=2020.11` and it says this:

`CondaError: Invalid spec for 'conda update': anaconda=2020.11 Use 'conda install' instead.`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Anaconda documentation is outdated. The correct command is now:

```
conda install anaconda=2020.11
```